# CPP Header file struct error

Tags: c++, struct, header

here is my header `level.h`:

```
#ifndef LEVEL_H_
#define LEVEL_H_
    #include <string>
    #include <map>
    #include <queue>
    #include <list>

    typedef struct {
        std::string title;
        int stepsAmount;
        std::queue <std::list <char> > steps;
        std::queue <std::map <std::string, int> > stepsOptions;
    } Level;
    std::string getCurrentStepExpression(Level* level);
#endif
```

And my `level.cpp`:

```
#include "level.h"

std::string getCurrentStepExpression(Level* level) {
    std::string result;
    if (level)
        result = level->stepExpressions.front();
    return result;
}
```

Everything seems okay, but compiller says:

```
..\level.cpp: In function 'std::string getCurrentStepExpression(Level*)':
..\level.cpp:12:19: error: 'struct Level' has no member named 'stepExpressions'
```

why it doesn't see my struct's fields?

Comment: I think the problem is that 'struct Level' has no member named 'stepExpressions'.

Comment: Everything is ok, excepts that you don't have stepsExpressions in the struct Level. Take a look, you have stepsOptions.

Comment: Oh god, i'm an idiot =)

Comment: front() returns a queue not a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add a stepExpressions member or stepExpressions() method to your struct Level and pass in some index to lookup in steps.

```
struct Level {
    std::string title;
    int stepsAmount;
    std::queue <std::list <char> > steps;
    std::queue <std::map <std::string, int> > stepsOptions;
    /* add the method stepExpressions to your class */
    std::list& stepExpressions(int step);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`stepExpressions` is not part of your struct.
Try adding it.